# Remmina VNC - how to automatically accept connection

Tags: remmina

I am trying to connect remotely from an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop to another Ubuntu 22.04 desktop via the internet through VNC on Remmina. The connection works finely, but in order to connect on the connected computer I have to click "accept" which I do not want, because the computer is unattended. How can I enable automatic acceptance?

Comment: Have you installed and set up a VNC server on the remote desktop or are you using the legacy option of built in Gnome Remote Desktop feature?

Comment: I am not aware of a VNC server in particular. I am applying the sharing options in the Ubuntu 22.04 settings.

Answer (score 2):

### Setup Gnome Remote Desktop with a password

**Note: This has nothing to do with the Remmina on the local computer.** You have to set it up in the **remote computer**.

This option is somewhat hidden. Go to the **system Setup** > **Sharing** on the left panel >

1. Turn on Sharing toggle at the right side of the top bar.
2. Click on the Remote Desktop to open the Remote desktop window.
3. Make sure the toggle the remote desktop connection is on.
4. Check the box for **Enable legacy VNC Protocol**
5. Click on the three dots <kbd>⫶</kbd> next to the **Enable legacy VNC Protocol**
6. Click on the radio button **Require a Password**
7. Make sure the the **Remote Control** toggle is on.

See the picture below:

[image]

The username and password will be at the bottom of the screen, not shown in the picture. You may change them.

I strongly advice everyone to set the remote access password to something long and random particularly if the remote connection is over the internet. You don't want some hacker to guess and get into your remote computer.

### Save the usename and password in Remmina

If you don't want Remmina to ask for the username and password every time you try to connect you may save these within Remmina's **Basic Tab**. These are what you set in the Remote Desktop settings and can be different from your login username and password.

Hope this helps

Comment: When I do this, I just get a black screen. But when I use the "New connections must ask for access" it works, though i have to login to the remote using TeamViewer to accept the incoming.

Comment: @Colin Thanks for your comment. I had no problems a few days ago. After I read your comment and I was able to reproduce the problem. The black screen had a square lighter black area in the middle, where the cursor turned into an "x". I toggled the option from "Require a password" to "New connection must ask for access" and I was able to connect as you described. I changed it back to "Require a password" and **rebooted the remote computer**. After the reboot, I logged in locally to the remote computer. Then remote access using Remmina worked again with password!

Comment: @Colin please ask a new question. I will convert this comment to a full answer. Then you can accept the answer as correct.

Comment: thank you - rebooting the remote worked a treat! The password screen shows up now on the local properly and all is well :-)

Answer (score 1):

On the remote computer you set the `vino-server` option for this.

Using `dconf-editor` go to /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/ and toggle off the `prompt-enabled` setting.

Then restart `vino-server`

Comment: how do I restart the vino-server?

Comment: Also, it seems to ignore the prompt-disabling, even after a relog

Comment: Note, `vino` is not installed by default in Ubuntu 22.04. VNC desktop sharing is handled by `gnome-remote-desktop`'s legacy toggle in the System Setup app. By default `gnome-remote-desktop` uses the RDP protocol (without installing `xrdp`).